# Missing decimals when printing

Tags: c++

Below is some simple code I am working with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float f = 1.66f;
    int d = (int)f;
    double g = (double)d;
    cout.precision(6);
    cout<<g<<"\n";
}
```

I want it to print `1.000000` but it prints only `1`. But, even after upgradation of int to double, doesn't it automatically convert it to an integer value?

Comment: Well if you do cout << 1.0000; you ll get the same thing.

Comment: Easy fix - `cout<<g<<".000000\n";`

Comment: Is it the problem with `cout`. Will it work with `printf``?

Comment: @JonathanPotter, what does returns it means?

Comment: @JohnLui Sorry, ignore me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You can add `cout << std::fixed;`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float f = 1.66f;
    int d = (int)f;
    double g = (double)d;
    cout.precision(6);
    cout << std::fixed;
    cout<<g<<"\n";
}
```

and you get `1.000000`

**Explanations (edit)**

When you use [std::fixed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/) :

> When floatfield is set to fixed, floating-point values are written
>   using fixed-point notation: the value **is represented with exactly as
>   many digits in the decimal part as specified by the precision field**
>   (precision) and with no exponent part.

When you use the [std::defaultfloat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/defaultfloat/) (the one you are using)  :

> When floatfield is set to defaultfloat, floating-point values are
>   written using the default notation: **the representation uses as many
>   meaningful digits as needed** up to the stream's decimal precision
>   (precision), counting both the digits before and after the decimal
>   point (if any).

That's why the following `.000000` are considered irrevelant !
(If you had `1.00001` it would have been printed)

Comment: But, isn't `cout.precision()` and `cout<<fixed<<setprecision()` isn't the same thing?

Comment: Nope see the example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/)  the results are different

Comment: @JohnLui: Why would they be?

Answer (score 1):

Setprecision sets how precise the result has to, e.g.

```
std::cout << (1.f)/6 << std::endl;  // prints 0.166667
std::cout.precision(7);
std::cout << (1.f)/6 << std::endl;  // prints 0.1666667
```

But it does not require that 0's are printed out, consider:

```
std::cout.precision(5);
std::cout << 1.1110f << std::endl;      // prints 1.111
std::cout << 1.1111f << std::endl;      // prints 1.1111
```

And as coincoin suggests the solution to get 0's printed out is to use std::fixed!

Comment: Explains the problem but doesn't answer the question

Comment: The exact question is "doesn't it automatically convert it to an integer value", pretty meaningless, if you ask me. So you should try to solve the problem

Comment: I got it. But I just had one doubt, setprecision sets how precise the result has to be, and not how many digits have to be printed? What's the difference between the two?

Comment: One difference as you see is that 0's need not be printed out. The other things is that some floats have a lot of digits. Setprecision sets how many digits need to be accurate,